# JQ: Numeric field names

Tags: json, powershell, jq

I use JQ 1.5 in a Windows10 enviroment (PowerShell).
I built a `jq` statement that works on the example data on jqplay but throws a error on my enviroment:

Sample: [Code share](https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb8adb0a)

Code:

```
. | { last_update:  .starbase_detailed_scan.last_update_time, user_name:  .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_name, alliance_id: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_alliance_id, drydocks: .starbase_detailed_scan.num_drydocks, tier: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_level, defence_plattform: .starbase_detailed_scan.num_defence_platforms, shield_triggered: .starbase_detailed_scan.player_shield.triggered_on, shield_end: .starbase_detailed_scan.player_shield.expiry_time, parsteel: .resources."325683920".current_amount, tritanium: .resources."743985951".current_amount, dilithium: .resources."2614028847".current_amount, user_id: .starbase_detailed_scan.owner_user_id, defence_rating: .starbase_detailed_scan.defense_rating }
```

The problem are the JSON objects with a numeric identifier. On jqplay I got the correct values. On PowerShell `jq` I get an error. I expected that this is a PowerShell problem so I tried to move the filter into a filter file. The error is then gone but I get only NULL as value for the three objects.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't use `jq` from PowerShell. PowerShell comes with its own JSON parser, so just use that.

Comment: That filter you added there isn't valid anyway. What are you actually running?

Comment: updated the filter. Had a copy and paste error in

Comment: @TimoC Why would anyone click that link and copy that ginormous JSON, and work on it? Can't you just include a small but representative example in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers in the json path need to be marked Oldschool like:
.starbase_detailed_scan.resources["2614028847"]

BR
Timo